# Can't create new wallet via RPC

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, rpc, wallet

I tries create new wallet from bash, but when i call create_wallet request is freezed and wallet-rpc writes:

```
2019-09-30 09:30:08.230 T [sock 0x561888dca810] new connection from 127.0.0.1:57864 INC to 127.0.0.1:18090, total sockets objects 2
2019-09-30 09:30:08.230 T New connection from host 127.0.0.1: 0
2019-09-30 09:30:08.230 T Setting 00:20:00 expiry
2019-09-30 09:30:08.230 D  connection type RPC 127.0.0.1:18090 <--> 127.0.0.1:57864 (via 127.0.0.1:57864)
2019-09-30 09:30:08.230 T Setting 00:20:00.054968 expiry
2019-09-30 09:30:08.230 D SSL detection buffer, 278 bytes: 80 79 83 84 32 47 106 115 111
2019-09-30 09:30:08.230 D That does not look like SSL
2019-09-30 09:30:08.230 T Moving counter buffer by 1 second 0 < 613604 (last time 0)
2019-09-30 09:30:08.230 T Throttle throttle_speed_in: packet of ~278b  (from 278 b) Speed AVG=   0[w=1]    0[w=1] /  Limit=16 KiB/sec  [278 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
2019-09-30 09:30:08.230 T Moving counter buffer by 1 second 0 < 613604 (last time 0)
2019-09-30 09:30:08.230 T Throttle <<< global-IN: packet of ~278b  (from 278 b) Speed AVG=   0[w=1]    0[w=1] /  Limit=16 KiB/sec  [278 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
2019-09-30 09:30:08.231 T HTTP HEAD:
Host: localhost:18090
User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 137


2019-09-30 09:30:08.231 I HTTP [127.0.0.1] POST /json_rpc
2019-09-30 09:30:08.231 I [127.0.0.1:57864 INC] Calling RPC method create_wallet
2019-09-30 09:30:08.237 W Español word 'asa' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.237 W Español word 'ave' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.237 W Español word 'boa' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.237 W Español word 'cal' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.238 W Español word 'dar' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.238 W Español word 'don' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.238 W Español word 'dos' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.238 W Español word 'eco' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.238 W Español word 'eje' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.238 W Español word 'fax' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.238 W Español word 'feo' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.238 W Español word 'fin' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.238 W Español word 'gen' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.238 W Español word 'gol' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.238 W Español word 'haz' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.239 W Español word 'ira' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.239 W Español word 'luz' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.239 W Español word 'mar' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.239 W Español word 'mes' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.239 W Español word 'mil' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.239 W Español word 'oca' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.239 W Español word 'ojo' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.239 W Español word 'ola' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.239 W Español word 'oro' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.239 W Español word 'oso' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.239 W Español word 'pan' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.240 W Español word 'pez' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.240 W Español word 'pie' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.240 W Español word 'red' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.240 W Español word 'res' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.240 W Español word 'rey' is shorter than its prefix length, 4
2019-09-30 09:30:08.265 E Exception at [connection<t_protocol_handler>::handle_read], what=bad_function_call
^C2019-09-30 09:30:57.853   D JOINING all threads - almost
2019-09-30 09:30:57.853 D JOINING all threads - DONE
2019-09-30 09:30:57.853 I net_service loop stopped.
2019-09-30 09:30:57.853 W Stopped wallet RPC server
2019-09-30 09:30:57.854 W Saving wallet...
2019-09-30 09:30:57.854 W Successfully saved
2019-09-30 09:30:57.854 T [sock -1] Socket destroyed without shutdown.
2019-09-30 09:30:57.854 T [sock -1] Socket destroyed
2019-09-30 09:30:57.854 D Destructing connection #1 to 0.0.0.0
2019-09-30 09:30:57.854 T [sock 8] Socket destroyed without shutdown.
2019-09-30 09:30:57.854 T Closed connection from host 127.0.0.1: 1
2019-09-30 09:30:57.854 T [sock 8] Socket destroyed
2019-09-30 09:30:57.854 D Destructing connection #0 to 127.0.0.1
```

My request like in docs:

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:18082/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"create_wallet","params":{"filename":"mytestwallet","password":"mytestpassword","language":"English"}}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Config

```
rpc-bind-port=18082
rpc-bind-ip=0.0.0.0
confirm-external-bind=true
daemon-login=root
daemon-address=127.0.0.1:18081
wallet-dir=./wallets
disable-rpc-login=true
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your request is correct? The wordlist being used is "Español" yet in your example request, you are using "English".

Comment: Yes, this is the main trouble. I definitely use English in request. May be try Espanol?)

Comment: No, wallet ignores any language in param and using Espanol.

Comment: Is it actually creating the wallet or just giving warnings?

Comment: Wallet stucks after this messages

Comment: It looks like just warnings because regardless of language used, the language words are loaded/checked and there is an issue with the spanish wordlist it seems (the min lenght is stating 4 yet there are some words ony 3 chars long). This warning should not prevent the wallet creation though.

Comment: "Wallet stucks after this messages": but what happens if you wait? What return message/code do you get?

Comment: Nothing happens. But if I kills the process of wallet-rpc I got **Empty reply from server**

Comment: If I try to open created with cli wallet from rpc I get an error. I think this is a complex problem throughout the wallet-rpc.
```
{
  "error": {
    "code": -1,
    "message": "Failed to open wallet"
  },
  "id": "0",
  "jsonrpc": "2.0"
```

Comment: Don't kill the process. Call it and wait. You will eventually either get a response or a timeout.

Comment: Unless you changed `zmq-rpc-bind-port` on the daemon, you are asking the daemon to create a wallet. `18082 Port for ZMQ RPC server to listen on` or did I miss something?

Comment: If I wait wallet answer I got ```curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Comment: Just see the config, I change ```rpc-bind-port```

Answer (score 1):

You have given a login for the daemon, but no password. monero-wallet-rpc is an unattended program, so does not prompt. You need to pass the password after the login, with a separating colon, like this:

--daemon-login root:pass

Arguably, there should be a --prompt-for-daemon-password option, which would override the unattended part.

Comment: It's nothing change

Comment: I assume you mean the fix did not work for you. It worked for me. Makes sure you do it correctly. The current wallet (0.15.0.0) prints a message when this happens.